# Update selected value of a dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart

I have custom dropdown input class that am re-using. The second instance of the class is dependent on the first one. The items of the second dropdown depend on the selected value in the first instance.

The dropdown code:

```
class DropdownInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  final String hint;
  final Function(String?) onValueChanged;

  const DropdownInput(
      {super.key,
      required this.items,
      required this.hint,
      required this.onValueChanged});

  @override
  _DropdownInputState createState() => _DropdownInputState();
}

class _DropdownInputState extends State<DropdownInput> {
  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //selectedValue = "l";
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(),
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
        ),
        child: DropdownButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
          isExpanded: true,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          dropdownColor: Colors.grey[100],
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          iconSize: 24,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
          underline: Container(),
          items: widget.items.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          value: selectedValue,
          hint: selectedValue == null ? Text(widget.hint) : null,
          disabledHint: selectedValue == null ? Text(widget.hint) : null,
          //hint:selectedValue == null ? Text(widget.hint) : Text(selectedValue!),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = newValue;
            });
            widget.onValueChanged(newValue);
            // if (newValue != null) {
            //   widget.onValueChanged(newValue);
            // }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the usage of the above class:

```
class NewCustomer extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewCustomer({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewCustomer> createState() => _NewCustomerState();
}


class _NewCustomerState extends State<NewCustomer> {
  
  List<String> zoneIds = [];
  Set<String> areas = {};
  double progress = 0;


  Future<void> fetchAreas(String id) async {
    try {
      // Specify the document path you want to retrieve
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('zones').doc(id).get();

      // Check if the document exists
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          areas.clear();
        });
        var data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        if (data.containsKey('areas')) {
          var areasData = data['areas'];
          setState(() {
            areas = Set<String>.from(areasData);
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching areas: $error');
    }
    print('areas in the list: ${areas}');
  } 

  @override
  void initState() {
    getZoneIds().then((ids) {
      setState(() {
        zoneIds = ids;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<String>> getZoneIds() async {
    final zonesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('zones');

    //List<String> zoneIds = [];

    var snapshot = await zonesRef.get();

    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
      zoneIds.add(doc.id);
    }

    return zoneIds;
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
            height: 5,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
                value: progress,
              ),
            )),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              
              DropdownInput(
                items: zoneIds,
                hint: "Select Zone",
                onValueChanged: (String? value) {
                  if (value != null) {
                    
                    fetchAreas(value); // Fetch new areas based on the selected zone
                    //print(value); // Print the value here, in the usage code
                  } else {
                    // If no zone is selected, clear the areas list and set selected area to null
                    setState(() {
                      areas.clear();
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
             DropdownInput(
                items: areas.toList(),
                hint: "Select Area",
                onValueChanged: (String? value) {
                  print(value);
                },
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When i run the app and select 'zone' value everything works perfectly and the areas is updated and the 'areas' dropdown work as well. But if I change the value of 'zones' dropdown after i had selected the 'areas' value, I get the error below. My aim is that if i change the value of zones, the 'areas' dropdown should be cleared and the hint text shown so that i can select another value

Error message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building DropdownAreas(dirty, state: _DropdownAreasState#43a60):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Bulanda.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 948 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  DropdownAreas
  DropdownAreas:file:///home/blessedson/flutter_workspace/water_staff/lib/pages/addcustomer.dart:311:15

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      new DropdownButton (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:948:15)
#3      _DropdownAreasState.build (package:water_staff/pages/utils/input.dart:357:16)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5583:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5471:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#8      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#15     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#17     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#25     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#28     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#30     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#32     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#33     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#34     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5547:5)
#35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#36     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:858:37)
#37     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:759:35)
#38     Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:347:35)
#39     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:806:24)
#40     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:735:7)
#41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#44     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#45     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#46     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#48     Element.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3964:32)
#49     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6896:17)
#50     _ViewportElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:235:11)
#51     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#52     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#54     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#55     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#56     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#58     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#60     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#61     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#62     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#63     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#64     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#65     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#66     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#67     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#68     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#69     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#70     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#71     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#72     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#73     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#74     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#75     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#76     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#77     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#79     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#80     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#81     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#82     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#84     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#86     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#88     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#89     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#90     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#91     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#92     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#93     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#95     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#96     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#97     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#98     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5657:5)
#99     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#100    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#101    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#102    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5800:5)
#103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#104    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#105    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#106    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5547:5)
#107    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#108    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6743:14)
#109    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#110    Element.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3964:32)
#111    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6896:17)
#112    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3815:15)
#113    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
#114    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
#115    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#116    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2895:19)
#117    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:984:21)
#118    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:457:5)
#119    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1325:15)
#120    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1255:9)
#121    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:978:7)
#125    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```